# Most informative DEF CON talk?

Tags: professional-education, attacks

I didn't make it to DEF CON this last year...

I'd like to know what you thought was the most interesting/informative presentation and possibly a link to more information on the topic.

[mod - switched to community wiki]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wimaxx-hacking.. I think these guys have the slides on their google group.

[click here](https://groups.google.com/group/wimax-hacking?pli=1)

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on where your interests lie. There were several good talks about several topics. There was a good talk by Dave King about using Arduino as a hacking tool.
The UAV talk was particularly entertaining and was also physical computing based.
The ATM talk was a great insight into the vulnerabilities of embedded OS's, namely XP embedded, which runs on ATMs, POS devices and several other hardware solutions to sensitive data transfer.

There was a great talk on social engineering as well.

There was definitely something for everyone, make sure you make it this year and we'll hook up for some partying.

Comment: I think your first sentence was supposed to be a comment on @Joey's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Barnaby Jack from IOActive was the guy for ATM hacks.

http://www.scmagazineus.com/black-hat-2010-researcher-jack-uses-design-authentication-flaws-to-force-atms-to-spit-out-cash/article/175803/

Lots of interesting news articles on this and lots of video if you google for this.